# .htaccess redirects using wildcard at end of URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to use .htaccess redirect to go from

http://myurl.com/100#foo to http://myurl.com/100#bar

where the number 100 is a post number and can be any number.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: URL after hash `#` is not sent to server by browser.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously `.htaccess` cannot resolve this as per my earlier comment.

If you decide to use Javascript then following script can be used in your page.

```
if (location.href.indexOf("#foo") > -1) {
   location.assign(location.href.replace(/#foo/, "#bar"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `#` and everything after it is a [URL Fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), and it's never sent to the server. You'll have to find a solution on the browser's end in order to change that, probably javascript.

When the browser requests:

http://myurl.com/100#foo

The only thing that gets sent to the server is:

/100

thus there is *no way* the server can know about the `#foo` part.

Comment: OK that sounds like it then. Thank you. I'm sorry that I'm a new user and can't vote you up yet.